# Chrome and FF wrong window height

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, primefaces

There is a big application with many pages.

When in console I do `console.log($(window).height())` on any page of the application, the result is as expected: the height of the window, not the document. For example:

```
$(window).height() //351
$(document).height() //1037
```

But there is one page, where on the first load this result is wrong in Chrome45 and FF38: it gives the height of the document minus 1px. For example:

```
$(window).height() //2753
$(document).height() //2754
```

If I reload the page, the result is correct, like on any other page.
There is a lot of javascript there: jquery, jqueryui.1.8.23, primefaces, jquery plugins. etc.

But I can't find, what can cause such a strange behaviour. On IE11 everything is ok.
What can be a reason of this wrong calculation of `window.height`? Can you give any ideas, where to look?

Comment: I had this issue with ff before. Try using .outerHeight and .outerWidth. These take into account padding etc. This is usually down to padding/margin/borders.

Comment: Any idea what causes the issue? Why on reload everything is ok?

Comment: I'm not sure sorry, looking at this again I had a slightly different issue. However, seen as though it's on first load that it does this, I would think it could be a timing issue. If there is javascript setting the heights dynamically then I would step through it.

Comment: Is it possible to change $(window).height dynamically?

Comment: At what point of the pageload are you running that console.log? One of your JS resources could be affecting that value. Try removing them one at a time to see which one, if any, is causing this discrepancy.

Comment: I run `console.log()` after the page is completely loaded. I try with removing the JS resources. Can it be the JS fault, if other pages have the same scripts and on reload this page is acting normally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone needs the solution:

The problem was caused by the doctype of the document. All the pages had `<!DOCTYPE html>` but this one had something like `<!DOCTYPE composition PUBLIC ..bla...XHTML 1.0 Transitional..bla...>`. On the reload the doctype became the same as other pages. Maybe something related to this jQuery bug : https://github.com/morr/jquery.appear/pull/16

The correct doctype resolved this issue.